# Comparing 2 arrays from 2 different spreadsheets, and writing their complement to the 2nd spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pulling data from a master document.  I was using the `=IMPORTRANGE` solution, but noticed that when someone filtered the master doc, it would then change my second spreadsheet as well (a problem because there are a couple columns where I'm inputting additional data).

I'd like to write a script that:

1. puts all the info in a range from spreadsheet 1 into an array
2. puts the existing info from a range in spreadsheet 2 into a different array
3. checks to see what is new on the first spreadsheet that isn't on the second spreadsheet
4. and then adds that info to the second spreadsheet.  Here's what I've got so far...

Here's the [first spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bUDzevRV1urlndILAAfJBXcnh-Isy_oEJleV9OlLZ8o/edit?usp=sharing) and the [second spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YXjAxndJAzQB_pMQqzHG7tFjphoU1M8Pmsx0q4PLk7w/edit?usp=sharing).

```
function importNewData() {
  var dataFrom = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1bUDzevRV1urlndILAAfJBXcnh-Isy_oEJleV9OlLZ8o").getRange("A2:A200").getValues();
  var dataTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B200").getValues(); //first row is just headers, so we start on 2
  var newData = new Array (); 

  var dataFromLastRow = 0;
  var dataToLastRow = 0;

  for (var i in dataFrom){ //finds the last row by assuming the row before the first blank row "" is the last row
    dataFromLastRow = i;
    if(dataFrom[i][0]==""){break}
  }

  for (var j in dataFrom){
    dataToLastRow = j;
    if(dataTo[j][0]==""){break}
  }

  dataFrom.length = dataFromLastRow; //sets array to just the cells that have data
  dataTo.length = dataToLastRow;

  for(k=0; k<dataFrom.length; k++) {
    for(l=0; l<dataTo.length; l++) {
      if(dataFrom[k][0] !== dataTo[l][0]) {
        // the extra square brackets will make it a 2D array, 
        // aligning it vertically -- code from Jacob Jan Tuinstra
        newData.push([dataFrom[k][0]]);
      }
    }
  }

var toPaste = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2+dataToLastRow,2,newData.length);
  toPaste.setValues(newData);

}
```

First of all, if the second spreadsheet range is empty, it says

> "The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 43, file "Code")."

I'm guessing this is because newData isn't showing as zero, but as nothing.  So there's that...

The for loop within a for loop seems to be pushing unique entries twice, and non-unique entries once... Not sure what I should change here to to only push unique entries and only do it once.  If the second range has 3 entries, then it does unique entries 3 times and the others twice.

Finally, on the last little bit where we write back to the spreadsheet, it's concatenating the 2 and the `dataToLastRow` variable instead of adding them.  I feel like there's something really obvious that I'm missing here.

Also, if there's an inefficiency, or even a style mistake, let me know, as I'm trying to learn JS better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First of all, if the second spreadsheet range is empty, it says "The
>   coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 43, file
>   "Code")." I'm guessing this is because newData isn't showing as zero,
>   but as nothing. So there's that...

This should be happening if the script cannot find any data to write into the second sheet, i.e. when there are no values that are not already in CopyTo.
GAS then tries to write an array to a range when it needs to write an array of arrays (even if it is just `[[]]`).

> The for loop within a for loop seems to be pushing unique entries
>   twice, and non-unique entries once...

Whenever that loops finds a row in dataTo that is not equal to the value you are currently checking it adds it to `newData`.
Try looping through the second array, when you find the entry set an `inCopyTo` variable to `true` and `break`, if it traverses fully and `inCopyTo` is `false` *then* add the row to `newData`.

Not tested:

```
for(k=0; k<dataFrom.length; k++) {
    var inArray = false;
    for(l=0; l<dataTo.length; l++) {
      if(dataFrom[k][0] === dataTo[l][0]) {
        inArray = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!inArray) {
      newData.push([dataFrom[k][0]]);
    }
  }
```

> Finally, on the last little bit where we write back to the
>   spreadsheet, it's concatenating the 2 and the dataToLastRow variable
>   instead of adding them. I feel like there's something really obvious
>   that I'm missing here.

Arrays are special cases of objects. Every key (index for arrays) is always a string. You need to cast it to an integer with `parseInt(dataToLastRow)` first.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  For the first issue, should I put in an if loop for if newData is blank?  Just wondering how one would normally deal with that situation.

Comment: Yes you could use something like `if(newData.length) {/*write data to spreadsheet*/};`